# Easiest way of accessing deep-nested value in json response?

Tags: php, json

I have the following response (I cut the extra short):

```
{
    "meta": {
        "current_page": "1",
        "last_page": "1",
        "per_page": "15",
        "total": "1",
        "from": "1",
        "to": "1"
      },
      "Products": [
          {
              "archived": "0",
              "committed_stock": "0",
              "created_at": "2015-05-10T17:39:53+00:00",
              "deleted": "0",
              "description": "desc",
              "id": "43061710",
              "links": {
                   "Users": [
                      {
                        "id": "107534",
                        "type": "created_by"
                       }
                    ],
                   "Attributes": [
                     {
                        "id": "31538870"
                     }
                   ]
             }
          }
       ]
}
```

Everytime I get this response, there will only be one item in "Attributes." What is the easiest way of grabbing this value? So far I have this:

```
  $json = json_decode($json_data);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$json = json_decode($json_data, true);
echo $json["Products"][0]["links"]["Attributes"][0]["id"];
```

Comment: the return value of json_decode is not a JSON anymore. JSON is always a string. JavascriptStringObjectNotation. better do something like $obj = json_decode() or $arr = json_decode()

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
var_dump( $json->Products[0]->links->Attributes);
```

the object field could be ether also an object, or an array:

- refer to  field: $object->object
- refer to array's i cell: $object->array[i]

P.S.
please edit the json, it's missing it's end...

Answer (score 0):

You may also want to try some JSON Path libs for PHP: https://github.com/Peekmo/JsonPath